# I am trying to get input using Alert Dialog box but getting a run time error in Android

Tags: android, user-input, android-alertdialog

Here is My Code
    package com.dialog;

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;




public class Main extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);            
    final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);        
    final EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
    final EditText contact=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.contact);
    final HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<String,String>();
    Button button_add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.main_add);
    final AlertDialog alert;



    builder.setCancelable(true)
    .setPositiveButton("Add",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                map.put(contact.getText().toString(), name.getText().toString());


            //Toast.makeText(Main.this,map.get(contact.getText().toString()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",new  DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });



    builder.setView(textEntryView);
     alert=builder.create();



    button_add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alert.show();

        }
    });







}
```

}

Her are my two xml files:

1)main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"
    />
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/main_add" android:text="Add"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

2)dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_label"
        android:text="Name:"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name_label"
        android:hint="Enter your name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_label"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:text="Contact:"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/contact"
        android:layout_below="@+id/contact_label"
        android:hint="Enter the contact number"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>





</RelativeLayout>
```

Help me!!!

Comment: Put your logcat error file too. Only then the users will know what the problem is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
final EditText name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
final EditText contact=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.contact);
```

You look them up from `main` layout, not from dialog. Should be:

```
final EditText name=(EditText)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.name);
final EditText contact=(EditText)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.contact);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AlertDialog dialog = new Builder(Main.this.getParent()).create();
dialog.setTitle("Delete");

dialog.setButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
dialog.setButton2("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

        // Whatever you want to do
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});

dialog.show();
```